# How do you get the nid from an entity id?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I've got a field collection attached to a node. Given the entity ID of a given instance of that collection, how do I obtain the nid to which it's associated?

When using entity_load, the nid for some reason is a protected property, so I can't access it. I must be missing something.

Update: using node_load on this entity ID returns false.

Comment: If you use node_load() instead of entity_load() you should be able to access it. Any particular reason why you are using entity_load()?

Comment: I had no idea you could use node_load(). Nice! I will try this.

Comment: I don't see it in the node_load() object. What am I looking for?

Comment: node_load() takes the nid as the argument. :-)

Comment: Guys, I know how node_load works. It returns false when I give it this entity ID (which is for a field collection).

Answer (score 4):

It's important to understand that if all you have is the id of *any* entity, then there is no way to load a specific entity with that id. Since entity_id's are not unique across entity-types, it is necessary to know both the entity type, **and** the entity id.

See [Developers need an $entity->entity_type property](http://drupal.org/node/1042822) for a discussion on changing this for D7, as well as info about how this will be likely be handled in D8.

On the other hand, as pointed out in a different answer, if you already know that the entity id is a node id, then you can call an entity specific load function like `node_load($nid)`. Since most entities will have such a load function to support named arguments, such a "shortcut" function will be almost universally available.

Examples: [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7), [taxonomy_term_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7), [commerce_product_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--commerce--modules--product--commerce_product.module/function/commerce_product_load/7).

Answer (score 3):

In this example Classroom is a content type (entity) with a field called `field_students`. `field_students` is a node reference field, and it references nodes (entities) of content type Student.

```
// Get all the Student items attached to a field. 
$studets = field_get_items('node', $classroom, 'field_students');

// Get the node id of the Student entity in the first field entry.
$student_nid = $studets[0]['nid'];

// Create a full object (node) representation of the student.
$student_obj = node_load($student_nid);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a field collection